# TinyMCE how to support page breaks in content pasted from Word

Tags: tinymce-5

TinyMCE has a plugin (PowerPaste) that supports pasting content from Word.

TinyMCE also has a plugin (Page Break) that supports adding page breaks to documents.

However. Using an editor instance that has both of these plugins enabled (such as the one on this page https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/full-featured/) pasting content from Word that contains page breaks, using the 'Retain Formatting' option when prompted, does not result in those page breaks being retained in the pasted content.

This seems like a bug. Does anyone know whether this is indeed a bug, or just a missing feature, and most importantly whether there is some way to get this to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE has a plugin (Page Break) and TinyMCE also has a plugin (Print Preview). Page Breaks don't show in Print Preview.